# How to retrieve full profile of linkedin user via Javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve the full profile (especially job history and educational qualifications) of a linkedin user via the Javascript API. I have managed to piece together the following code from google and stack overflow:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   blahblahblah
    onLoad:    onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInLoad() {
   IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
}
function onLinkedInAuth() {
   IN.API.Profile("me").result(displayProfiles);
   // IN.API.Profile("me").fields(["industry", "network", "date-of-birth", "educations:(id,school-name)"]).result(displayProfiles);
}
function displayProfiles(profiles) {
   member = profiles.values[0];
   document.getElementById("profiles").innerHTML =
   "<p id=\"" + member.id + "\">Hello " + member.firstName + " " + member.lastName + "</p>";

   for(education in profiles.educations) {
      var id = education.id;
      var name = education.schoolName;
      console.log(name);
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="IN/Login"></script>
<div id="profiles"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This manages to retrieve the logged in user's name and surname after they grant access. However it completely fails to retrieve anything else. I am using a company login for linkedin and I can access all the user's information via the rest api, so it's not an access issue; I just don't know (and can't find any examples) of how to use the Javascript API. How would I specify what information to retrieve and how would I then identify that information in the returned JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work on my end by using a variation of the call you had commented out:
Check the [fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/full-profile) you can use, you had "network" in there but it is not listed. Maybe it was part of an older version of the API?

```
function onLinkedInAuth() {
  // IN.API.Profile('me').result(displayProfiles);
  IN.API.Profile('me').fields([
    'first-name', 'last-name', // Add these to get the name
    'industry', 'date-of-birth', 'educations:(id,school-name)',
    'positions' // Add this one to get the job history
  ])
  .result(displayProfiles);
}
```

Then you can work with the returned data like this:

```
function displayProfiles(profiles) {
  var member = profiles.values[0];

  // Note that these values are arrays and not objects
  var educations = member.educations.values;
  var positions = member.positions.values;

  document.getElementById('profiles').innerHTML =
   '<p id="' + member.id + '">Hello ' + member.firstName + ' ' + member.lastName + '</p>';

   educations.forEach(function(edu) {
     var id = edu.id;
     var name = edu.schoolName;
     console.log(id, name);
   });

   positions.forEach(function(position) {
     // Do some work with each position...
   });
}
```

Comment: Gives me a TypeError: member.educations is undefined

Comment: For positions it sort of works, but it only returns the current position; not all positions.

Comment: Sounds like your app is only set for [r_basicprofile](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) permissions. Go into your [app page](https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/) in linkedin developer and make sure your "r_fullprofile" box is cheked.

Comment: For some reason "r_fullprofile" is not even listed, even though it's a corporate account.

Comment: r_fullprofile is also not listed on my non-corporate account.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right place? I see it on my free personal account, I can't imagine why they would not have this for paid users. It is under "Default Application Permissions" in the authentication tab, same page where you get the Client ID.

Comment: Apparently you now have to apply to get r_fullprofile.

Comment: Does anyone know how to apply ? I just need my own full profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch user profile data then you can modify the linkedin profile badge using javascript and get data of user without authtoken and api

**LinkedIn-Profile-Data-Fetch-Without-API-Using Javascript with profile badge**

```js
let lkList = ["devsalmanshaikh", "ravi95"];
let linkedinid = "";
let idx = 0;
let badgeElm = document.getElementById("hideBadgeElm");
let waitObserver;

getData();

function getData() {
  linkedinid = lkList[idx];
  badgeElm.innerHTML = `<div class="badge-base LI-profile-badge" data-locale="en_US" data-size="medium" data-theme="light" data-type="VERTICAL" data-vanity="${linkedinid}" data-version="v1"><a class="badge-base__link LI-simple-link" href="https://in.linkedin.com/in/${linkedinid}?trk=profile-badge">.</a></div>`;
  loadProfileJs();
}

function loadProfileJs() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.onload = function() {
    waitObserver = setInterval(domObserve, 1000);
  };
  script.src = "https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js";
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}

function domObserve() {
  let state = badgeElm.querySelector(".LI-profile-badge .profile-badge__header");
  if (state) {
    clearInterval(waitObserver);
    console.log(state);
    let json = {
      id: linkedinid,
      img: "#",
      name: "Not available",
      title: "Not available",
      info: "Not available",
    };

    if (badgeElm.querySelector("img.profile-badge__content-profile-image")) {
      json.img = badgeElm.querySelector("img.profile-badge__content-profile-image").src;
    }

    if (badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-name")) {
      json.name = badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-name").innerText;
    }

    if (badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-headline")) {
      json.title = badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-headline").innerText;
    }

    if (badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-company-school-info")) {
      json.info = badgeElm.querySelector(".profile-badge__content-profile-company-school-info").innerText;
    }

   
    showData(json);
  }
}

function showData(json) {
  let tbl = "<table border=1><tbody>";
  for (i in json) tbl += `<tr><td class='col0'>${i}</td><td class='col1'>${json[i]}</td></tr>`;
  output.innerHTML += tbl + "</tbody></table>";
  idx++;
  if (idx < lkList.length) getData();
}
```

```html
<div id="output" style="padding: 12px;"></div>

<div id="hideBadgeElm" style="display: none;"></div>
```